# Trying to connect to MSSQL database using JetBrains/Exposed

Tags: android, sql-server, kotlin

What is the correct URL format to connect to my mssql server?  Per the quick start on github it's:

```
Database.connect("jdbc:h2:mem:test", driver = "org.h2.Driver")
```

This doesn't seem correct to me as my server is not h2.  I am new to android development and I don't do a lot of database work, mostly front-end development, but I am learning Kotlin.  I am using JetBrains/Exposed in my project as it says it works with SQL server syntax.

Comment: I found that Database.connect("jdbc:sqlServer://doghorn.arvixe.com;DatabaseName=dbname", driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", user = "username", password = "password") seems to connect but I get "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlServer" error.

Answer (score 1):

They have an example of an SQLServer connection on the wiki: 
[link](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DataBase-and-DataSource#datasource)

```
Database.connect("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:32768;databaseName=test", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", 
             user = "root", password = "your_pwd")
```

//Gradle

```
compile "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.4.0.jre7"
```